# Which nonlinear assert is complete in smt/z3 optimize?

Tags: z3, smt, nonlinear-optimization

I list some assert about Quadratic function:

```
(declare-fun H () Int)
(assert (>= H 8000))
(assert (<= H 12000))
(minimize (- (^ H 2) H))
(check-sat)
```

but the answer is "unknown" and the reason for unknown is (incomplete (theory arithmetic)); I can't understand which is the lost one

Comment: sorry, i failed to make it clear, the code is not for java compiling but the result in SMT formation compiled from java.

Answer (score 0):

In general z3 cannot deal with non-linear terms. (A term is non-linear if you multiply two variables together. In your case, that'd be `(^ H 2)`.

This is especially true of the optimization engine: Nonlinear constraints over integers is most likely going to be beyond reach. But you're in luck: Your formula is rather simple so it can handle it fine. Rewrite it using multiplication:

```
(declare-fun H () Int)
(assert (>= H 8000))
(assert (<= H 12000))
(minimize (- (* H H) H))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This prints:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun H () Int
    8000)
)
```